# Difference in interpreting partial correlations and single factor CFA estimated correlations –

Tags: factor-analysis, partial-correlation

I am new to statistics and performing single factor analysis (since I have a good idea on the observed variables) and modifying the structure based on the residual matrix (using proc calis) but not able to understand the difference in the below figures.

Let’s say if I have 3 variables X1, X2 & X3 and I have a fair idea that X1 and X2 will represent a single factor and want to modify the factor structure (if needed) after running a single factor analysis. So I ran the CFA defining a single factor for all 3 observed variables, it estimates the co-variances and also gives me the “Asymptotically standardized residual matrix” and chi-square so that I can modify my factor structure such that it fits best with the data.

My question is – how the partial correlation of X1 and X2 controlling X3 is different from the estimated co-variance of X1 and X2 (from factor analysis)? 
I am thinking both the below figures is giving me the same thing (i.e. estimated covariance of X1 and X2 = partial correlation of X1 and X2 controlling X3) –

Please provide the answers such that a lame man can understand. And pointing any references is highly admired. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I found the below article very useful for understanding the difference between estimated correlation (or co-variance) matrix from factor analysis and the partial correlations. http://node101.psych.cornell.edu/Darlington/factor.htm

Comment: A factor is a new, 4th variable. It is "created" from the dataset, but it isn't its linear function. It has nothing to do with the concept of partial correlation among the variables.